# Android C2DM getting NotRegistered response

Tags: android, android-c2dm

Thank you for reading my post:

I had C2DM working perfectly in my application.  To test a different scenario I unregistered my phone so that it would not receive pushes anymore, and then I re-registered my phone.  Since I have re-registered push does not work.

Here are the steps I'm experiencing:

1. My phone receives a registration_id with no erros
2. I do a post to Google with my registration_id within a few minutes of receiving the id
3. I get a response of Error=NotRegistered

I don't see anything strange in LogCat during this process.  I'm at a loss and any help is much appreciated.

Thank you,
Matt

Comment: If the permissions were not setup right in my phone would I even receive a registration_id from Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using the C2DMMessaging class provided by Google to do push and you're calling the static method C2DMMessaging.register(Context context,String senderId), you must pass in the senderId that you registered for C2DM with.

It will still give you a registration id back from the C2DM servers if you use an account on the phone, but it will not work for your purposes.

Thanks,
Matt